# Distribute canvas gradient colors evenly given an arbitrary color range

Tags: html, math, canvas, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to distribute a `canvas` linear gradient evenly given a random color range. Something like this.

```
let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")[0];
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);

// generate some random colors
let random = Math.round(Math.random() * (10 - 2) + 2)
let colors = Array.from( Array( random ).keys() ).map(function(){
    return '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
});

// loop through the colors and add color stop with percentage. 
colors.forEach( (color, index) => {
    let percentage = (index / colors.length) / 1;
    console.log(percentage);
    gradient.addColorStop(percentage, color);
})

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100);
```

This issue with this is that it's not even. It inevitably ends up with a longer gradient at the end. How can I calculate the percentage to that the gradient is event across the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the formula to

```
let percentage = index / (colors.length - 1);
```

because the index goes from `0` to `colors.length-1` inclusive.

This way every transition will get the same amount of pixels.

Comment: I did try that but it gives me the center of the gradient instead of the end (or colorStop). I need to subtract have the width of the color somehow and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: For example, if I had a three colors in my array your math would give me `[0, .5, 1]`, but what I need is `[.33, .66, .99]`.

Comment: @Pardonner to make an evenly distributed gradient of 3 colors, you do need 0, 0.5, 1. Your .33 .66. 99 would create a solid color from 0 to 0.33 and from .99 to 1

Comment: Ahh yes. I'm looking at this again and my issue is that my fillRect width is 150, while my actual gradient width is 200. This is why none of my gradients looked right. Thanks for chiming in @Kaiido